# Is it possible to wait for two Web Elements at the same time in Robot Framework via Xpath?

Tags: xpath, robotframework, element, wait, keyword

I have two Web Elements and if one of them appears it should trigger a keyword.
But i dont find anything in the web to connect a logical operation like OR/AND into my XPATH...
Is there a possible workaround??

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible ||| //body/div[@id='app']/div[${count1}]/div[${count2+2}
```

but the trigger shoud be
${count2+2} OR ${count2+1}

Comment: show your code trials and errors?

Comment: is the question unmistakable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before anything else: this is not a question of Robot Framework but on how to work with xpath and identify elements in the page.

So if you want to search 1 div or another div, just find the "thing" that clearly identify each and then:

```
//div[@this='first' or @that='second']
```

If the elements are in different nodes/levels, you can always do:

```
(//div[@this='first']) | (//div[@that='second'])
```